# ¿Cómo cambiar el Platform Target a X64 en Visual Studio en un proyecto?

Tags: c#

[image: este es el proyecto]

necesito hacer la conexión a una base de datos Oracle y para ello debo activar el Platform Target a X64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenida a la comunidad.

Puedes hacerlo desde las propiedades del proyecto > compilación > plataforma de destino
[image]

También puedes hacerlo desde el menú al lado de ejecutar (play)
[image]

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sea útil.